# Connecting to JMX hosted on Heroku

Tags: heroku, jmx

I have an add-on in my app that is hosted on Heroku in a private space. That add-on is exposing a JMX_URL in the config vars. I want to build my own health metrics page that would connect to the JMX of the add-on, read properties from mbeans and expose them. 
JMX_URL has the following format:

```
jmx://username:password@host:port
```

How do I properly construct a valid JMX service URL and establish a successful connection? Should my app also be hosted in the same private space in order to do that? Any help would be appreciated on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I've made it work, in order to connect to the JMX of the add-on that is running within a private space, one should access it from the app that is running in the same private space, also add-on's certificate has to be registered in the client's app keystore to avoid SSLHandshake errors. Here is the code snippet that establishes a connection:

```
String url = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://[host]:[port]/jmxrmi";
JMXServiceURL serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL(url);
Map env = new HashMap();
String[] creds = { "user", "password" };
env.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, creds);
JMXConnector cc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL, env);
MBeanServerConnection mbsc = cc.getMBeanServerConnection();
```